# Page Jump within long answer

Tags: discussion

So recently I wrote a pretty long answer to a question on [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), the question I am referring to is: [Who died in One Piece](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26478/who-died-in-one-piece). The answer was relatively long and I was wanting to add a page jump to each letter to allow a user to just click on the letter they were wanting to see instead of having to scroll all the way down, which could take quite a while depending on the letter. I was trying to accomplish this using the href but it doesn't seem to work is there any way to create a page jump for my answer?

Comment: No, such thing does not exist.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well that's unfortunate makes reading lists like that a pain for people.

Comment: True, but Stack Exchange was not really built for such long answers. This is pretty rare corner case. (Doesn't mean I don't support your idea, I do, but does explain the lack of official response)

Comment: There probably is away for me to make the answer shorter by changing picture sizes and formatting it to run horizontally. I'll have to play with it to see what I can get.

Comment: Yup, something like this should work: `<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/mYwbW.jpg" height="50" title="Banchina" /> <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/OnqhJ.jpg" height="50" title="Bell-mere" /> <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/dvOra.png" height="50" title="Busshiri" />`